# Why can't a jQuery object be appended more than once?

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to understand why a jQuery object can't be appended more than once:

#### jQuery

```
var $divObj = $('<div/>', { 'text': 'This is a div!' });

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#example').append($divObj);
});
```

#### Markup

```
<div id="example"></div>
<button>Add Div</button>
```

This only works the first time the `button` is clicked. Subsequent clicks don't appear to do anything.

I know that I can use `clone()` when appending the object, or can pass the `div` as a string, **but I'm looking for an explanation as to why appending an object doesn't work more than once**.

#### [Here's a sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNHLX/1/)

Comment: The root cause is that that's how JavaScript objects are passed around: by reference. Whenever you need to copy an object, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: From the [`.append` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/): *"If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)"*. Since this is similar to the behavior of the DOM API, it kind of makes sense.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Not really. It's what jQuery has decided to do. If he was to append to multiple places in the DOM at the same time, jQuery *would* clone the element for him. It's only when it's appended to a single place that jQuery detaches and moves.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, that makes sense. I didn't spot that when reading the documentation

Comment: @Matt - Yes, it's a jQuery design decision, but they basically adhered to the principle of least surprise and followed the JavaScript behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `$divObj` holds a reference to a DOM element (well, a jQuery object, but that just wraps the DOM element). When you append that element to the DOM, `$divObj` still refers to that same object. It doesn't magically duplicate it when you insert it into the DOM.

As you said, you can use `.clone()` to create a new copy of the node, which can be appended again in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after total loading of the page it is not taking the value from $divObj.
If you want to show the message every time you click what you can do is to put the $divObj inside on click function and it will work.
Here is the code changes.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var $divObj = $('<div />', { 'text': 'This is a div!' });
    $('#example').append($divObj);
});
```

Thanks